# How to set flag10g in oracle 12 using sqldeveloper?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I was trying to look up the syntax for doing this. I used the following:

```
alter session set flag10g='TRUE'
```

I get SQL

`Error: ORA-02248: invalid option for ALTER SESSION`

This line above worked for other parameters that I set but not this one. I'm guessing it's because it has to do with SDO_GEOMETRY but I haven't found anything to say how to set this parameter.

Is there a way to set this in sqldeveloper?

Comment: This is not a session/system parameter. This is the parameter of a procedure, check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11830/sdo_objgeom.htm#SPATL1130)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know `flag10g` is a parameter of [SDO_GEOM.VALIDATE_GEOMETRY_WITH_CONTEXT function](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/sdo_geom-validate_geometry_with_context.htm#SPATL1130) or [SDO_GEOM.VALIDATE_LAYER_WITH_CONTEXT procedure](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/sdo_geom-validate_layer_with_context.htm#SPATL1132).

See at [Spatial and Graph Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/) for details.

Comment: That bridged the gap of my understanding. I thought that it was an oracle parameter.